# Comparison between Cross Document Messaging and WebSockets

Tags: html, websocket

If I understand correctly, the Cross Document Messaging API allows you to send and receive messages between Web pages in real time.

While WebSocket allows you to send and receive objects between the website and the server in real time.

Can one replace the other to build a web application real-time?

If not, which the mechanism is better, and for what?

Comment: What is the "Cross Document Messaging API"?  When I google for that, it isn't clear to me exactly what you're asking about.  Are you just talking about `window.postMessage()` that can be used to communicate between open browser windows in the same browser?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about window.postMessage()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window.postMessage()` is used to communicate between cooperating browser windows both open in the same browser.  It sends message directly from the Javascript in one window to the Javascript of another window.  It only works between two web pages open in the same browser.  It cannot send data to a web page open in some other browser.

A webSocket connection is a completely different thing. It is a socket connection between a client and a server.  Since browsers support the webSocket interface, you can make a webSocket connectfion from a web page to a server.  Once the connection is established, data can be sent either from web page to server or from server to web page.

A webSocket cannot be used to directly connect two web pages.  It could be used to get information from one web page to another, but you'd have to have both web pages connect to the same server and then have one web page send data to the server and the have that server send that data to the other web page.  This is how many chat programs work.

`window.postMessage()` cannot be used to send data to any other computer so it only has use between windows in the same browser.